# Updated Spring MVC Framework Tutorial

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there any updated tutorial for this or something similar to this - 
http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/?

I like this tutorial as it covers a simple system step by step. But it's outdated and all the other tutorials including Spring site don't have a clear tutorial. They show a topic at a time when this one shows building a simple system incorporating various elements. Is there any tutorial similar to this with latest spring framework?

Comment: In case no one answers, don't hesitate to open an [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and request updated documentation.

Comment: @ManuPK Sorry but I found this site better and closer to the mvc tutorial: http://krams915.blogspot.com/

Comment: @ZiG: well there are number of good spring MVC resources available in the web. I was trying to answer how the spring team provided the tutorial similar to what you have shown for version 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a better version of that?

[Here](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/) is a **SPRING MVC 3 SHOWCASE** from the **SPRINGSOURCE BLOG** by **Keith Donald**.

> The first showcase I've put together is for Spring MVC 3, our web framework. It includes a sample project, along with a supporting slide presentation and screencast. After digging in, you should have a good understanding of what Spring MVC can do and get a feel for how easy it is to use.

It contains a user guide, video presentation of the features and working source code hosted on the [github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase).

Comment: do you know of one for springmvc version 3? some of the classes do not match (2.5 to 3) and i guess there are improvements in the API?

Answer (score 1):

There are many books (e.g. Spring In Action) and tutorial out there that you can check.

One online tutorial using Spring Framework MVC 3.1. with annotations that I would recommend is: [Spring Framework MVC 3.1 Tutorial](http://www.flacom.com/spring-framework-mvc-3-1-tutorial)

The tutorial is not yet so comprehensive, but there you would be guided in every single step how to make a working web application. The complete source codes are also available to download.

Good luck in learning Spring Framework.